# How can i embed multiple system prompts into my chatbot?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am using openai and am defining system prompts in my messages.

If i want to add more than one system prompt such as following:

1. your response must be limited to 2 line
2. your response must not be rude
3. your repsonse must be in english or German depening on language from query

how can i incorporate such system prompts below?

```
Query = 'What are the top 3 dress designs?'

messages = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a creative fashion designer."},
              {"role": "user", "content": Query},
              {"role": "assistant", "content": "1. Tunic dress 2. Tea dress 3. Kimono dress..."},
              {"role": "user", "content": "continue"}]
```

I don't understand the role of 'assistant' ; what exactly is meant to go here, when the chatbot can have more than one response and user can more than one query? I have put an example of a query there but this will be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to prompt 3 separate system prompts, instead you could just create a single one concatenating all 3 commands, but if you must, you can do it like:

```
messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "Your response must be limited to 2 lines."},
    {"role": "system", "content": "Your response must not be rude."},
    {"role": "system", "content": "Your response must be in English or German depending on the language from the query."},
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a creative fashion designer."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "what is what?"},
]
```

assistant is the role of ai, so the response will have a final element with the role of assistant.

you can check it out here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/making-requests